# Am i able to calculate ($a^{bc}$ mod d) with ($a^{b}$ mod d) and ($a^{c}$ mod d) without knowing a power?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, exponentiation, cryptography

So I am trying to calculate  ($a^{bc}$ mod d) with the values I have:

($a^{b}$ mod d) and ($a^{c}$ mod d)

In a scenario where I do not know what is **c**, but I know the integer values of ($a^{b}$ mod d), ($a^{c}$ mod d), **a**, **d** and **b**,

is there a way to calculate  $a^{bc}$?

Thanks all!

Comment: When you say you "know" those values, do you know them as integers or just as residues $\pmod d$?

Comment: I know them as integers.

Comment: So why not take $\left( a^c\right)^b \pmod d$?

Comment: whoops, you are right. Thank you!

Comment: This is closely related to [Diffie–Hellman key exchange](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffie–Hellman_key_exchange), if you want to read more about these operations.

Comment: Yes! This is a variation of DH key exchange but was confused as to how its shared key was calculated mathematically.

Answer (score 1):

This is [Diffie-Hellman Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman_problem) on composite modulus - assuming $d$ is a composite number.

**Diffie-Hellman Problem**

Let $g$ be a generator of some group, in general, it is the multiplicative group of a finite field or an elliptic curve group.

Formally Diffie-Hellman Problem can be stated as:

> Given an element $g$ and the values of $g^x$ and $g^y$, what is the value of $g^{xy}$?

In Diffie-Hellman key exchange, $x$ and $y$ are chosen randomly.

---

If the group order is not a prime and if you know the factors of $d$;

- you can calculate the discrete log for each prime factor of $d$ (assuming distinct) then you can use CRT. This requires that you know the factorization of the $d$. If the factors are not distinct, you will need the special case of CRT.
- you can use [Pohlig-Hellam Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pohlig%E2%80%93Hellman_algorithm) which is works best if the prime factors are small.

  If $d = \prod_i p_i^{e_i}$ then it has comlexity $$\mathcal O\left(\sum_i {e_i(\log n+\sqrt {p_i})}\right)$$ compare it to the other generic discrete log agorithms with $\mathcal O(\sqrt{d})$-complexity.

If any factors of the $d$ are larger than 180-bit, you cannot calculate it with the current technology since the collective power of BitCoin miners can reach $\approx 2^{92}$ double SHA256 calculations in a year as of 2020.

As a result, your success will depend on the value and factors of $d$.